# How to prove $\frac{\mathcal{B}(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{6})}{3} = -\mathcal{B}(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{6})$

Tags: integration, gamma-function, beta-function

Recently I solved an integral with answer $\frac{\mathcal{B}(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{6})}{3}$ and WolframAlpah solve the same problem with answer $-\mathcal{B}(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{6})$. Both are same value.
How to prove the are same value using Beta function identities?

Answer (score 2):

Try using
$$ B(a,b) = \frac{\Gamma(a) \Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$$
and the properties of the gamma function

Comment: gamma(1/6) = 6gamma(7/6) and 2gamma(1/2) = -gamma(-1/2)

Comment: Exactly so the product $\Gamma(1/6) \Gamma (1/2) = -3 \Gamma(-1/2) \Gamma(7/6)$ while the denominator is unchanged, so that you get your equality

Answer (score 0):

$$LHS=\frac{1}{3}B(1/2,1/6)=\frac{\Gamma(1/2) \Gamma(1/6)}{3\Gamma(2/3)}$$
Use $\Gamma(1+z)=z\Gamma(z)$, then
$$RHS=-B(-1/2,7/6)=-\frac{\Gamma(-1/2) \Gamma(7/6)}{\Gamma(2/3)}=2\frac{(-1/2)\Gamma(-1/2)(1/6)\Gamma(1/6)}{\Gamma(2/3)}=LHS $$